# Do you need a unique IP address for each Amazon API query?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 5 clients. Each of them have their own Amazon API key. I'm running requests for them from my server. Can I run simultaneous requests from a single IP for multiple API keys?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from trying, but you'll need to make sure that the AWS IAM policy attached to each key allows for requests for that API key from your external IP address.

For a practical example, you can think of the S3 API. Say each client has a key with R/W access to the same bucket. Each key is associated with an IAM user that has a policy attached to their account. That policy will answer your question. If it only allows access to S3 from an IP address other than your own, you will not be able to do anything. However, if it has open access (bad), or access from their IP and yours (good), then you shouldn't have any issues.